# Cannot create file with fsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, node-webkit, nwjs

I'm working with [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/) and my application have to create files on the disk so I used [fsjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsjs) to do that.

Problem is when I install my app (after packaging) on a windows10 machine I can't create files anymore and I got this problem :

> EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'path/to/file.txt'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
>       at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1223:33)

When executing :

`var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFileSync(path, content, "utf-8");`

The problem is solved when I run the application in administration mode.

So obviously the problem is related to some kind of permission under windows10 `c:`, is there a way to fix that programmatically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The fix is simple: Don't write to the system root directory.

Comment: I'm not, this problem is for any directory.

Comment: Certainly you didn't try all directories to claim that this were happening for *"any directory"*. Anyway, the question is unclear. We don't know, **where** you are trying to write. The fact that running under an account with administrative rights appears to succeed is a strong indication, that you are writing to a protected location. Again, the fix is simple: Don't try to write into protected locations.